# OSX: iTerm2 JavaScript for automation scripting

Tags: javascript, macos, iterm2

I'm trying to send a command to execute at startup, when I open a new iTerm2 window, but I'm not able to find the way:

```
iterm = Application("iterm");
win = iterm.createWindowWithDefaultProfile();
sess = win.tabs[0].session[0];
cmd ="cd ~/tmp";
iterm.write(sess,{text: cmd});
```

will open the new window and then:

```
execution error: Error on line xxx Error: can't convert types (-1700)
```

Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Append the **s** character to '**session**' --> `sess = win.tabs[0].sessions[0];` , or you can use : `sess = win.currentSession();`